# Examples of models that generate networks with small world properties?

Tags: graph-theory, network

I know that a small world network has two properties: small average path length (like that of a random graph) and high clustering coefficient (like that of a lattice graph). The classic model for this type of network is the Watts-Strogatz model (aka Small World Model).

However, I want to know if there are other models that can capture these properties, especially those that are not modifications of the Watts-Strogatz model.

I have tried different graph generators (i.e., network generation models) using [NetworkX's Graph generators](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html), but they returned networks with very low (<< 0.5) average clustering aside from the Watts-Strogatz model.

Some references to other small world models that I could implement with Python would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You (and a lot of other people) got some things mixed up. Small-world networks are networks with a geometrical basis and long-range connections. The Watts–Strogatz model is a way to create such networks, which happen to have high C and low L. Some people interpret high C and low L as equivalent to being a small world. But, for example, if you take a rectangular grid and add long-range connections (i.e., Watts–Strogatz with another basis), you will get a network that is clearly a small world, but has a low C. (This doesn’t invalidate your question though.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the classic Watts-Strogatz model you're not gonna get a local clustering coefficient above 0.7.

Another model you can use the Holme-Kim model, or the modified Holme Kim model proposed in https://doi.org/10.1017/nws.2016.5 where you start with a small base network and add nodes with connections either forming triangles, or not, giving you a tuneable clustering coefficient. However this also only gets you a maximum $CC \approx 0.7$. These networks give you a degree distribution that is closer to scale-free.

You can also implement your own Watts-Strogatz type model, but have the starting network being the caveman network, or connected caveman network from networkx, which has $CC \approx 1$, and rewire from there, and with some modification you can keep a uniform degree-distribution.